# JS import class into already imported class

Tags: javascript, import, promise

I have a NodeJS API with several model files. In the JSON object for the A class, I need the JSON object for the B class so I did something like this.

A.model.js

```
const { B } = require("./B.model.js");

export class A {
    constructor(...) {...}

    // Retrieve Data for the A object 
    static methodA(x) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
               const B = await B.methodB(y).then(data => {return data})
        }
    }
}
```

B.model.js

```
export class B {
    constructor(...) {...}

    static methodB(y) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               ...
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked but when I then needed some data from the A object inside the B object I thought I could simply import the A class like before with

```
const { A } = require("./A.model.js");

export class B {
    constructor(...) {...}

    // Retrieve Data for the B object 
    static methodB(y) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
               const A = await A.methodA(x).then(data => {return data})
               ...
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get the error
`TypeError: cannot read property "methodB" from undefined`
Even though it worked before importing the B class into the A file.

Anybody knows why it happens ? I could go around the usage of the "crossed" imports by changing my SQL request in the methods but I'd rather not have too many joins.

Thank you

Comment: You seem to be mixing ES module and CommonJS module syntax. But `export class ...` is not valid in either of these systems. Please post the code you actually have. Also, the methods you are declaring will only be accessible on instances of these classes, not the classes themselves. Lastly you are making it unnecessarily complicated for yourself if you use the `Promise` constructor with an `async` function.  You could just write `async methodA() { const B = await B.methodB(y); }`.

Comment: @FelixKling I can't really show the real code as this is not my project and the creator isn't really okay with me sharing it, but I edited the code as I forgot to add that both methods are `static` so I could call them without an instance. I also need to use an `async` function inside the `Promise` constructor as both of these objects needs to be independant and return promises

Comment: `export class ...` is still not valid code. And my point is that you don't need to use a `Promise` constructor at all.

Comment: Why did the `export class` and requiring it work if it isn't valid ?

Comment: Ugh sorry, it's actually correct. It's still strange to mix ES and CommonJS syntax. Why not use `import ...`? But the error seems to suggest that importing doesn't actually work. That would certainly happen if you have a cyclic dependency and you are trying to access `B` before that module has been completely initialized. When/where/how is `methodA` called?